# Why does this backslash string code throw a 'SyntaxError: incomplete input'?

Tags: python

This is puzzling behavior. When I type strings with a number of backslashes within the quotes, I get the error: `SyntaxError: incomplete input` (in IDLE interpreter).

But I also get this other more cryptic error when I run in the CMD shell: `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: truncated \uXXXX escape`

The latter implies that the interpreter can't properly read the last bytes somehow? What is going on with this here?

These `print` expression examples also yield the same error:

```
1 'c:\some\user\name'
2 'c:\some\user\name\my\mote\foo\bar'
3 'c:\some\user\name\no'
4 'c:\some\user\yame'
5 'c:\some\user\game'
6 'c:\some\user\\name'
7 'c:\some\user\name\eall\eoo'
8 'c:\some\user\name\eall'
```

Comment: \ is used for escape characters. Eg `\n` for a newline. If you want an actual backslash you need to use \\ or prefix your string with `r` like so `r'c:\some\user\name'`.